# For $N\geq 5$. Which one of the following inequality holds?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

For $N\geq 5$. Which one of the following inequality holds?

1. $\sum _{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}\le 1+\log \left(N\right)$
2. $\sum _{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}< 1+\log \left(N\right)$
3. $\sum _{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}\geq \log \left(N\right)$
4. $\sum _{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n} \leq \log \left(N\right)$

**My Attempt**

When I substitute $N=5$, I am getting Option(1), Option(2) and Option(3) are correct. How do I do it formally?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac 1  {k+1} <\int_k^{k+1} \frac  1 x dx < \frac  1k$. Sum this w.r.t. $k$ from $k=1$ to $k=N-1$. You will see that 1),2) and 3) are all true. You can see that 4) is false by taking $N=2$.